# Re-arranging xml using xslt considering element attribute value

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd

I have the following xml:

```
<Users>
  <User id="2" name="ABC" Division="HR"/> 
  <User id="3" name="xyz" Division="Admin"/> 
  <User id="4" name="LMN" Division="Payroll"/> 
  <User id="5" name="PQR" Division="IT"/> 
</Users>
```

I want to convert it using XSLT as given below:

```
<Users>
 <User id="5" name="PQR" Division="IT"/>
 <User id="3" name="xyz" Division="Admin"/>
 <User id="2" name="ABC" Division="HR"/> 
 <User id="4" name="LMN" Division="Payroll"/>  
</Users>
```

I am doing it according to the Division attribute value, there is no specific rule for that.
This is just a sample.
This is not a sorting, its a kind of template.Can i define my own order for Users and convert it using xslt?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no order I can see you have rearranged the 'User' elements. The rearrangement can be based on alphabetical order, in this case, in ascending or descending. How do you want it?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @Lingamurthy CS :There is no order as such. Its a kind of template. Can i define my own order for Users and convert it using xslt?

Comment: "*This is not a sorting, its a kind of template.*" Please expand your question by showing what such template would look like. Would it be hard-coded into the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes it can be hard coded. My requirement is to arrange users as given in my question. There is no way to apply any sorting methods.

Comment: Sorry all for the confusion..,Can you please answer to :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823720/re-arranging-xsd-xssequence-using-xslt-to-convert-to-another-xsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to rearrange nodes in XSLT, from simple alphabetical or numerical sorting, to complex grouping. If you can use XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 1.0 with extensions, you can usually get away with `<xsl:sort>` in templates or loops and functions. If you are restricted to XSLT 1.0 you can do basic sorting in templates or loops on node-sets, but will have to write more complicated algorithms for grouping (ex: Muenchian method).

Using your simple example I thought of some ways to rearrange the nodes. Process your example with the stylesheet below and you will see some examples.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Results>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Users" mode="sort-name-alphabetical-asc" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Users" mode="sort-division-alphabetical-desc" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Users" mode="sort-id-numerical-desc" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Users" mode="sort-by-number-of-chars-in-division" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Users" mode="sort-by-last-letter-in-name" />
        </Results>   
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="User">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Users" mode="sort-name-alphabetical-asc">
        <example>Sort by name, alphabetical, ascending</example>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="User">
                <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="text" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Users" mode="sort-division-alphabetical-desc">
        <example>Sort by Division, alphabetical, descending</example>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="User">
                <xsl:sort select="@Division" data-type="text" order="descending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Users" mode="sort-id-numerical-desc">
        <example>Sort by id, numerical, descending</example>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="User">
                <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number" order="descending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Users" mode="sort-by-number-of-chars-in-division">
        <example>Sort by number of total chars in Division + name</example>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="User">
                <xsl:sort select="string-length(@Division) + string-length(@name)" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Users" mode="sort-by-last-letter-in-name">
        <example>Sort by last letter in name</example>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="User">
                <!-- In XSLT 2.0 you can use node()[ends-with(@name, '')] -->
                <xsl:sort select="substring(@name, string-length(@name)-1, string-length(@name))" data-type="text" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can i define my own order for Users and convert it using xslt?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.can you please answer to this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823720/re-arranging-xsd-xssequence-using-xslt-to-convert-to-another-xsd