# Re-arranging XSD xs:sequence using xslt to convert to another xsd

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="PRO">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="LIC" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="SPEC" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="NPI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>   
    </xs:complexType>

   <xs:complexType name="LIC">
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="SPEC">
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="NPI">
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:element name="LIC" type="LIC">
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="SPEC" type="SPEC">
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="NPI" type="NPI">
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to re-arrange xsd  as given below:

```
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element ref="NPI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element ref="SPEC" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element ref="LIC" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
         </xs:element>
     </xs:sequence>
```

There is no specific rule for sorting but just this order is what needed.
This is just a sample.

Thanks in advance.
Biju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple `apply-templates` to control the order in which the identity transform is performed. This makes sense only for a relatively small number of `xs:element` elements that need to be rearranged.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="xs:sequence[parent::xs:complexType/@name='PRO']">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="xs:element[@ref='NPI']"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="xs:element[@ref='SPEC']"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="xs:element[@ref='LIC']"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="PRO">
         <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element ref="NPI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
         <xs:element ref="SPEC" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
         <xs:element ref="LIC" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>   
    </xs:complexType>

   <xs:complexType name="LIC">
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="SPEC">
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="NPI">
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:element name="LIC" type="LIC">
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="SPEC" type="SPEC">
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="NPI" type="NPI">
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```